Clion quick fix: suggesting including files with different quotation marks
I am using CLion 2024.1.3 with CLion Nova, working on a CMake C++ project.
When a missing #include is detected, a suggestion is given to add this directive.
However, it always uses the angular brackets. I would like it to use the quotation marks instead if the included file is part of the project I am developing. Is there a setting that controls that?

